# Push Notification services for Red Foundry built iOS Apps

Tags: iphone, xml, push, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an iPhone App on Red Foundry which is a XML based developmental platform. I want to integrate push notification services? Any provider who lets me do other than Red Foundry Themselves like urban Airship? Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

UrbanAirship offer a great push notification service.  I've used them a lot for previous projects and found them very easy to use.

Comment: Nick, So Urban Airship can even be integrated with third party tools?For example, third party tools which don't use Objective C for development. XML based platform.

Comment: Urban Airship provide a very simple RESTful web interface to the service.  You can send a notification from anything that can make a call to the restful service.  I've done it from PHP, Perl and Java.  And they're very helpful and responsive when asking questions.  I sound like I work for them!  I don't - honest!  Just very pleased with the service they provided me.

Comment: When asked Urban Airship, They said and I quote.. "I took a look at Red Foundary, I don't think the platform will allow you to integrate Urban Airship for your push services. It's too much of a high-level abstraction from the basic platform features we require to function.Sorry."

Comment: and asked them a way and they said, "If you could figure out a way to request push permissions and retrieve the device token on the device using Red Foundary, and make the appropriate Registration API call against our service, you might have a chance:
http://urbanairship.com/docs/push.html#registration

However, taking a look at the Red Foundary documentation, I don't think this is possible using that platform. If you figure out a way to do it, I'd be interested to hear though!"

Comment: Have you used Red Foundry before with Urban Airship?! There is no X-CODE involved here..we work on an intermediary XML layer.

Comment: Sorry, completely misread your original question.  I've got no experience of Red Foundry.  It looks from their website like you are supposed to pay them and use their push notification system.  But I have no further knowledge than that.  Sorry!

Comment: So thats the issue! Thanks for your time. :)